# Configure a pubsub node with strophe.pubsub plugin for multiple publishers or a create a whitelist

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

How do I use the strophe.pubsub plugin to configure a node for multiple publishers or a whitelist, e.g. "pubsub#leaf_node_association_whitelist" variable?

I tried to pass in an array but this didn't work.

```
options = {
   "pubsub#leaf_node_association_whitelist": array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an iq stanza manually with a Strophe stanza builder $iq.